# Concat all the arrays from different objects in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, concatenation, aggregation-framework

i 'am starting discovering `mongodb` , i'd like to concat the `images` to be in the same array

The example:

```
{user_id:01, images:[10,20,30,40,50]}
{user_id:02, images:[11,22,33,44,55]}
{user_id:03, images:[12,22,32,42,52]}
{user_id:04, images:[13,23,33,43,53]}
```

The result wanted:

```
 images:[10,20,30,40,50,11,22,33,44,55,12,22,32,42,52,13,23,33,43,53]
```

i found through the Doc the `$aggreagation` solution , here is what i have tried:

```
  db.results.aggregate([{ $project: { images: { $concatArrays: ["$images"]}}}])
```

but it just concat the array from the same object , in my case as i mentioned in `result wanted`to concat all the array having the name `images` from different objects as one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two steps:

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with const value (like `null`) as a grouping `_id` to get an array of arrays (from all documents) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to flatten all arrays

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            images: { $push: "$images"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            images: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$images",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: [ "$$this", "$$value"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks for the help , i tried to do this query but it gives me this error : `2018-05-08T14:56:35.743+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):5:16` via mongo CLI     , by the way my `mongoDB version is 3.4`

Comment: it's working , i was naming the field with a space thats why it didn't work thanks :-)

Comment: ,Is there a way please  to not show the tag field  `images` as i am supposed next to group all those numbers of `images` in a file

Comment: @Data_Geek the output of aggregate has to be a valid JSON (BSON) so either you can have on document with an array or many documents having single item which is not what you want to achieve I guess

Comment: i see what you mean , any way thanks for your time and the help

Comment: LOL, my answer got downvoted, too, for obscure reasons. Spooky!

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following aggregation query to get your result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$images" // flatten the "images" array into separate documents
},
{
    $group: { // group all documents
        "_id": null, // into the same bucket
        "images": { $push: "$images"} // and push every image entry into an array called "images"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0 // to get rid of the "_id" field if needed
    }
}])
```

Comment: it 's a version 2 of the solution , but how to not show the `_id` field ??

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this answer got downvoted, please?

Comment: i don't know how , i noticed that the problem ,the answers got down voted somehow